# Electromagnetic Field caused by accelerating and oscillating charge particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, photons

Will accelerating and oscillating charges will cause EM waves of different shapes ? As EM waves are always shown as sinusoidal Electric and Magnetic Fields perpendicular to each other. Does it mean that both accelerating and oscillating charges cause same EM waves ? Or there is some difference between the two ?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler will u please answer ?

Comment: If you understand the harmonic solutions of Maxwell's equations, then you can generate all possible solutions by Fourier transforms (it's a bit more complicated than that for problems with boundary conditions, but the principle is the same).

Comment: @Alex Oscillating charges are by definition accelerating, so your question is ill-formed.

Comment: will you please elaborate ?@MSha